# Should there be bubbles after a new Linoleum installation?

Tags: linoleum

I recently had new Linoleum installed in my kitchen and bathroom. They had to peice the Linoleum together in the bathroom and now I have bubbles forming at the seams where it was put together. The contractor has specified the Linoleum needs time to settle, but it does not seem correct. It was installed over a new subfloor (Greenboard) type of flooring. Is this correct for needing to settle?

Answer (score 5):

I've never heard or seen this myself.  If it wasn't glued or rolled correctly in the first place, it's not going to glue itself back down, especially not at the seams.  Call the installer back and make them do it right - rip it up and install new. Don't let them try and "fix" it.